# Filter and Replace value in a column based on another column

Tags: r, dplyr

Below is sample of dataset I have

```
structure(list(x = c("P", "P", "P", "P"), y = c("0", "0", "1", 
"0"), z = c("0", "0", "0", "CD")), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")
```

[image]

For the cohort of `P` present in `x`, I need to check if `z` contains `CD` or not, if it does then check for `1` values in `y`. If yes then replace `CD` by `X`

Desired output

[image]

`CD` and `1` are never present in the same row and group by `x` is necessary

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try a simple `ifelse` statement that checks for the sum of `y` being greater than 0 (i.e. a `1` exists) and `z` being 'CD',

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
 group_by(x) %>% 
 mutate(z = ifelse(any(y == '1') & z == 'CD', 'x', z))

# A tibble: 4 x 3
# Groups:   x [1]
#  x         y z    
#  <chr> <dbl> <chr>
#1 P         0 0    
#2 P         0 0    
#3 P         1 0    
#4 P         0 x
```

Comment: Forgot to mention my bad ``y`` column is character it has other character values but I need only 1 (value) filter so is it safe to convert to ``numeric``  or should I use ``any``?

Comment: If it only has 0 and 1 just turn it to numeric. No need to keep it a character

Comment: It has other character values apart from 0 and 1

Comment: Yeah just do `any` then

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution with `base R`, where `ifelse()` is used for replacement

```
df <- Reduce(rbind,lapply(split(df,df$x),
                          function(v) within(v,z <- ifelse(any(y==1) & z=="CD","X",z))))
```

such that

```
> df
  x y z
1 P 0 0
2 P 0 0
3 P 1 0
4 P 0 X
```